# EFI Boot loader - grubx64.efi - PXE provisioning - Foreman

Tags: uefi, bootloader, pxe, foreman

If anyone could help me on this, I spent quite a lot of time trying to deploy Ubuntu servers (EFI) with Foreman but there is an issue with grubx64.efi. Foreman support told me that I should ask Debian/Ubuntu developers to carry those patches, for example:

https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/grub-devel/2020-09/msg00037.html

He added: "Foreman depends on several patches that has been sent upstream by Red Hat developers".

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I found my answer @Fedora ...
https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/30/Server/x86_64/os/EFI/BOOT/

Hoping that a new grubx64.efi version will reach us soon enough ...
https://www.zdnet.com/article/intel-were-ending-all-legacy-bios-support-by-2020/

Regards,

Gueug

Comment: Where did you get the `grubx64.efi` file that was not working?  Was it http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/uefi/grub2-amd64/current/ ?  I don't know anything about the patches, I'm just curious.

Comment: Yes I took it there ...

Comment: Thanks for sharing the links with us. However, posting [answers depending on external links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/217657) is not the preferred way of answering on this site. Please [edit] your answer to include the relevant instructions (or post the link as a comment to the question if you have the required privilege). See [answer] for details.